Will each HttpServlet implementation class create its own servlet instance?
How many servlet instances will be created if I have two HttpServlet implementation classes?
As follows:
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet1",value = "/HelloServlet1")
public class MyServlet1 extends HttpServlet {

    public MyServlet1() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("get Request");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("post Request");
    }
}

and
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet2",value = "/HelloServlet2")
public class MyServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    public MyServlet2() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("get Request");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("post Request");
    }
}

Will it create an instance per extension or share the first Servlet instance created that first request incoming when the Application started?
Please help, really appreciate

Do read the spec.

One instance per servlet
Servlets are multithreaded by default. The methods in a single servlet instance can run simultaneously in different threads.
Therefore, if you deploy both servlets, your Servlet engine will create two instances - one instance for each servlet. Every request will be served by a separate thread i.e. both of these two instances can handle hundreds of requests simultaneously.
Note that servlets are not thread-safe by default. You are responsible for writing thread-safe code in your servlet.
Servlet specification
Do study the Servlet specification. The document is surprisingly readable.
See section 2.2. Number of Instances of Servlet 6.1. To quote:

The servlet declaration … controls how the servlet container provides instances of the servlet.
For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default), the servlet container must use only one instance per servlet declaration.

SingleThreadModel (legacy feature)
Formerly, Servlets could implement SingleThreadModel. This allowed the servlet engine to create one servlet instance for each request. This feature was deprecated in Servlet 2.4 specification, and removed in Servlet 6.0.
